# Implement the enqueue function for java ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, list, implementation

There is an enqueue function in class PersistentQueue as following:

```
public class PersistentQueue<E> {
private List<E> queue;

public PersistentQueue<E> enqueue(E e) {    
List<E> clone = new ArrayList<E>(queue);
clone.add(e);
return new PersistentQueue<E>(clone);
}}
```

This function returns a new array with object e added while doesn't change the original array. My work is to implement it and make it faster. Can anyone provide any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you be a little more specific about what you need?  What are you blocked on?

Comment: I think you cannot do faster than linear time and you need to be bad programmer to do it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas,

1. Implement your own List (or Collection) type,
2. In it implement a faster clone method (or other approach to copying),
3. Implement some other optimizations for your use case?